# Write and read a pyarrow schema from file

Tags: python, pyarrow

I'm transforming 120 JSON tables (of type `List[Dict]` in python in-memory) of varying schemata to `Arrow` to write it to `.parquet` files on ADLS, utilizing the `pyarrow` package.

I want to store the schema of each table in a separate file so I don't have to hardcode it for the 120 tables. As I iterate over my tables, I want to load each schema from file and transform the JSON data to Arrow by passing the schema.

```
import pyarrow as pa

data = [
    {"col1": 1, "col2": "a"},
    {"col1": 2, "col2": "b"},
    {"col1": 3, "col2": "c"},
    {"col1": 4, "col2": "d"},
    {"col1": 5, "col2": "e"}
]

# How to load the schema from file and parse it into a `pa.schema`?
my_schema = pa.schema([
    pa.field('year', pa.int64()),
    pa.field('somthing', pa.string())]
)
arrow_table = pa.Table.from_pylist(data, schema=my_schema)

# How to write this schema to file? 
arrow_table.schema
```

I could write a custom file format for the schema and write a parser that reads the (e.g. txt) file, transforming its content into the `pa.datatype()` stuff, but I hope there is an easier, "official" solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the meta data using [pyarrow.parquet.write_metadata](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.write_metadata.html#pyarrow.parquet.write_metadata) and read it back using [pyarrow.parquet.read_schema](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.read_schema.html)

```py
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

table = pa.table({"col1": [1,2,3]})

pq.write_metadata(table.schema, "table.metadata")
schema = pq.read_schema("table.metadata")
```